# Linux static routing : Ping a private network(Network Diagram Attached)

Tags: linux, networking, routing

[image: Network Diagram]

In the Network Diagram above my aim is to ping `192.168.20.20` from System A.
I do not want to configure the router.

For that to happen

1. All the traffic to `192.168.20.0/24` should be first forwarded to
   `10.200.8.14`
2. Then System B should have a route to `192.168.20.20.`

Is there any way to add a route in System A such that to reach network `192.168.20.0/24` the default gateway is `10.200.8.14.`
Even if such route is added, in order to reach `10.200.8.14` we still need the default gateway `10.201.11.1.`

Please suggest how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is VPN over SSH. See `man sshd_config` and search for PermitTunnel.

First, make sure that `PermitTunnel` (both hosts) is enabled and that `PermitRootLogin` ( on systemB) is `yes` or `without-password` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and that `sshd` is reloaded.

Next, login to the host 10.200.8.14 using:

```
# ssh -NTCf -w 0:0 10.200.8.14
```

The following step is to configure the interfaces with a dedicated VPN subnet (192.168.10.0 in this example):

```
systemA # ip link set tun0 up
systemA # ip addr add 192.168.10.10/32 peer 192.168.10.20 dev tun0

systemB # ip link set tun0 up
systemB # ip addr add 192.168.10.20/32 peer 192.168.10.10 dev tun0
```

Then add a route for the network behind System B:

```
systemA # ip route add 192.168.20.0/24 via 192.168.10.10
systemA # ping 192.168.20.20
```

Another approach is to use `sshuttle`. Install `sshuttle` from source or the package manager. Then run:

```
systemA # /usr/sbin/sshuttle -D --pidfile /tmp/sshuttle.pid --dns -r user@systemB 192.168.20.0/24
```

This will ask for `sudo` password since `iptables` is used to route traffic. You can alter the `/etc/sudoers` file using `visudo` to avoid asking for a password:

```
 systemA # visudo
 # add:
 myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables, /usr/bin/python
```

Some interesting references:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN
http://sleepyhead.de/howto/?href=vpn
https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed your steps for VPN over SSH.
But problem came with arp resolution.

After adding a route for 192.168.10.0/24.

```
System C : route add -net 192.168.10.0/24 p255p2
```

I issued following command for arp resolution

```
System B : sudo arp -sD 192.168.10.10 eth1 pub
```

Ping worked after these steps.

---

Are these steps necessary?